# creating new files in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, document-setup

seems like a silly question but is the "new document" window the only way to create a new document from scratch? i.e. using the presets or type your own size..

i'm not a graphic design, i'm self taught with adobe but frequently have to design something with photoshop/indesign at work. i'm often given pdf template for print or have a PSD background to use in indesign. is it not possible to create a new document using the PDF or a PSD file? currently to make anything in indesign i first have to open photoshop, import either the PDF template or open the PSD background file, get the dimensions of these and then type these dimensions into indesign. it's not a huge problem but it is a pain having to do this every time! seems quite silly i need to use photoshop to make the correct size document in indesign...

i've tried googling and searching here but not seeing a definitive answer or solution, either that or im not using the correct search terms..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the new document window is **the only way** to create a document.

Ok, you can also create new documents via Javascript, but I don't think you're looking for that.

No, you cannot drag PSD or JPG or anything else into InDesign and assume InDesign will create a new document with the size of the file you're dragging. No such native feature.

By default, InDesign **will only open** INDD files, everything else is placed (linked) after a new document has already been created.

Something **you can do** is create a document of whatever size, drag your PSD on the page, then adjust the page size in InDesign based on the placed PSD, using the 'Page Tool' and ALT+dragging the page edges to fit the linked PSD.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. ah yes the page tool is what i was hoping for however i just tried it and the page snaps back to its original size? am i missing something?

Comment: Instead of dragging, try entering the numbers into the dimension box after you select a page with the page tool.

Comment: Actually dragging is fine, but you need to hold ALT while dragging, so the page doesn't snap back to its original size.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Lucian!

Answer (score 0):

While you can open AI files in Photoshop and vice-versae, there are no native ways to accomplish this in InDesign. The client would need to supply an actual indesign file or template for you to open it.

There is a piece of software from Markzware that will allow you to open PDFs as InDesign files, but I'm a bit wary of these style of tools.
https://markzware.com/products/pdf2dtp/